# SWF files loads very slow in high resolution screens

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, retina-display

In my flash based project, I render swf files in browser flash player as swf pages.
While it works fine in screens with resolution below "1920 *1080", but has issues of very slow page loading in high-resolution screens like Mac Cinema display (resolution 2560*1440) and MacBook pro with retina display (resolution 2880* 1800).

I don't have any resolution specific codes in my project and I am not sure how can I reduce the loading time without having to worry about screen resolution of the machine.

I searched a lot for similar issues but without any success.

My flash player version is "15.0.0.152".

Answer (score 0):

Compress your swfs with LZMA compression (Lempel-Ziv-Markov chain Algorithm). Also you can try turning on hardware acceleration to GPU. That should speed up things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will definitely have a look at it.
SWF files in question here are generated using PDF files as input files and converted to swf using pdf2swf tool at my linux based server. is there any command line utility available for this purpose? Adobe suggests using Its Flash Professional CS6, which is not a desirable solution towards this.